# Connection with iOS application and Garmin Watch

Tags: iphone, connectiq

I have an iPhone app and I need to connect with Garmin watch to display some details from my native app to Garmin watch. I didn't get any idea. Kindly give me the support.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is the Garmin Connect IQ developer site. On there is a FAQ entry for using the Connect IQ Mobile SDK.

https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/connect-iq-faq/how-do-i-use-the-connect-iq-mobile-sdk/

Comment: Can I connect with real ios device and connect IQ stimulator?

Comment: Hi @Sujina Have you done this integration?